# Ekastic search does not give correct results when using special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a elastic search query of which matching is defined as below. When I  search for strings which contains "debug_acc+all" it gives the strings which has "debug_acc+". And when I search for strings which "Source/sysc_master", it does not give any results.

```
XContentBuilder mappings = null;
        try {
            mappings = jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .startObject("document")
                    .startArray("dynamic_templates")
                    .startObject()
                    .startObject("template1")
                    .field("match","*")
                    .field("match_mapping_type","string")
                    .startObject("mapping")
                    .field("type","string")
                    .field("index", "not_analyzed")
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endArray()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            return mappings;
        }
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: can you provide more informations? Which is the field you query against? What query you use?

Comment: I query against the field switch. I query as switch ~~ "Source/sysc_master"